# Calculating $\textrm{Res}_2 z^2e^{\frac{1}{z - 2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to calculate $\textrm{Res}_2 z^2e^{\frac{1}{z - 2}}$

roperty that I want to use is that when we expand function in Laurent series, residue equals to $b_1$, where $b_1$ is coefficient in expression $\frac{b_1}{z - 2}$

By expanding $z^2e^{\frac{1}{z - 2}}$ into Laurent series we have:

$$z^2 e^{\frac{1}{z - 2}} = z^2 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{1}{z - 2})^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{z^2 (\frac{1}{z - 2})^n}{n!}$$

Now the problem is that I cannot extract coefficient $b_1$ from $\frac{b_1}{z - 2}$.

Could you please give me a hand with calculating it?

Comment: Write $z^2$ as a polynomial in $z-2$.

Comment: Or compute $\textrm{Res}_0 (z+2)^2e^{\frac{1}{z}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the residue at $z=2$ . So you need the coeff of $\frac{1}{z-2}$.

You have $z^{2}=(z-2)^{2}+4z-4=(z-2)^{2}+4(z-2)+4$.

Using this you get $$z^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!(z-2)^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^{2}+4(z-2)+4}{n!(z-2)^{n}}$$.

So the Residue(Coeff of $\frac{1}{z-2}$) is :-

$$\frac{1}{3!}+4\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+4\frac{1}{1!}=\frac{1}{6}+6$$